# POSIX Path Variable of Containing Folder | Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I am requiring this script to store two variables.

1. checksum_path - The selected file POSIX path
2. checksum_parent_path - POSIX path of the selected file ($checksum_path)

I am having to implement the second variable (checksum_parent_path) to the script below.

```
    checksum_path=$(/usr/bin/osascript << EOD
    tell application "System Events"
    activate
    try
    set FileName to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "Please choose checksum file:" of type {"SUM"})
        on error
        set FileName to "!ERROR!"
        end try
        end tell
    EOD)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you !

Adrian

Comment: You can just use `dirname` to get the parent directory, for example `parent=$(dirname "$checksum_path")`.

Comment: thank you for your help red_menace, it is working !

Answer (score 0):

This should do it unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFile to choose file
    set checksum_path to POSIX path of theFile
    set checksum_parent_path to POSIX path of (container of theFile as alias)
end tell
```